# How to use HttpWebRequest to login to website?

Tags: c#, php, httpwebrequest

I am trying to rewrite some server php code which logs into a website, using the canonical HttpWebRequest usage found all over the net on C# sites:

```
HttpWebRequest BuildPOST(string url, string parameters)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST";
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);
    Stream os = null;
    try
    { 
         request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
         equest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
         os = request.GetRequestStream();
         os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); 
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("{0} HttpPost: Request error", ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
         if (os != null)
         {
              os.Close();
         }
    }
    return request;
}
```

called using:

```
string login_url = "http://www.sailonline.org/community/accounts/login/";
string login_post_data = "next=/windy/run/{0}/&password={1}&username={2}";  // race, pwd, boat
HttpWebRequest req = BuildPOST(login_url, string.Format(login_post_data, race, pwd, user));
```

The original php is:

```
include 'phplib.php';

$url = "http://www.sailonline.org/community/accounts/login/";
$postdata = sprintf("next=/windy/run/%s/&password=%s&username=%s", $race, $key, $boat);
$html = get_pipe_output(build_post_url($url, $postdata));
```

However, the C# code does not generate the same response from the server as the php code. Instead I get a page asking for login details (which were correctly input in the post to begin with).

I am somewhat new to network programming, and just cannot seem to figure out why this is happeneing. I have snooped the packets from my code, the page serving the php and the original login page on the website in question and cannot see **any** difference betwen the requsts, only that the one issued from C# code does not have the expected response.
All I can think is perhaps the php functions do something I am unaware of ??

Comment: Not sure what the exact problem is, but you should URL-encode the content you post (you can use HttpUtility.UrlEncode() for that).

Comment: Isn't that what the request.ContentType set does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create and set a CookieContainer on the request. Without that your request wont succeed. Looks like the page is sending cookies with the response.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 31 Jan 2011 23:53:23 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Mon, 31 Jan 2011 23:53:23 GMT
Vary: Cookie
Last-Modified: Mon, 31 Jan 2011 23:53:23 GMT
ETag: "ad806aa693ed8187c278f0fadfa92d01"
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie:  sailonlinesid=bcc2b5fe9980df3e741e8fe7279d61d4; Domain=.sailonline.org; expires=Mon, 14-Feb-2011 23:53:23 GMT; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
Connection: close
```

Comment: Thankyou SO much, you would not beleive how many hours i spent trying to figure this out before asking here on SE!