# How do I get and compare Certificates from web severs?

Tags: c#, java, authentication, httpwebrequest, certificate

I am trying to port Java code to C# and my success so far falls behind web certificates...
I can successfully get the same results passing in parameters w/o the comparison, but I feel this needs to be implemented...

This is the basic technique I'm using to sign on to the server and submit data: [How to use HttpWebRequest to login to website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849717/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-to-login-to-website)
...after that, I extract the data from the response stream. Everything works, but I am wondering if I should even need the comparison.

[Java] ~what is originally done

```
// connection is an HttpsURLConnection object
Certificate[] certs = connection.getServerCertificates();

byte[] bytes = getKey(); // gets the file.key byte array

Certificate c = certs[0];
PublicKey pk = c.getPublicKey();
byte[] data = pk.getEncoded();

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     if (data[i] == bytes[i]) continue;
     throw new RuntimeException("Public key mismatch");
}
```

[C#] ~what I'm currently trying to do

```
byte[] bytes = Properties.Resources.Key;
// connection is a HttpWebRequest object
X509CertificateCollection collection = connection.ClientCertificates;
X509Certificate c = collection[0];
// I'm practically guessing on the parameters because I'm new to the
// web handling in C#...
PublicKey pk = new PublicKey(
    new Oid(), 
    new AsnEncodedData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(urlParameters)), 
    new AsnEncodedData(c.GetPublicKey()));
byte[] data = pk.EncodedKeyValue.RawData;
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    if (data[i] == bytes[i]) continue; 
    else throw new Exception("Public key mismatch");
```